# Java regex match each group separately

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
String text = "new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265858, 5430, '3XL', 75, 0, '14.90',     '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265859, 5341, 'L', 55, 0, '14.90',     '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265860, 5459, 'M', 45, 1, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265861, 5446, 'S', 35, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265862, 5458, 'XL', 60, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265863, 5511, 'XXL', 65, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL')";
```

and regex:

```
String regex = "new SingleSizeProduct((.*))";
```

I want to match all 6 groups separately, but when I match the pattern, I get result like this:

```
(
[0] => new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265858, 5430, '3XL', 75, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265859, 5341, 'L', 55, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265860, 5459, 'M', 45, 1, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265861, 5446, 'S', 35, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265862, 5458, 'XL', 60, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265863, 5511, 'XXL', 65, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),
[1] => (422056, 1265858, 5430, '3XL', 75, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265859, 5341, 'L', 55, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265860, 5459, 'M', 45, 1, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265861, 5446, 'S', 35, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265862, 5458, 'XL', 60, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265863, 5511, 'XXL', 65, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),
[2] => (422056, 1265858, 5430, '3XL', 75, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265859, 5341, 'L', 55, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265860, 5459, 'M', 45, 1, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265861, 5446, 'S', 35, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265862, 5458, 'XL', 60, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265863, 5511, 'XXL', 65, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),
)
```

How can I match each group separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy so it will try to find maximal possible match meaning that `(.*)` will match

```
abc(foo)def(bar)ghi
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to make it find minimal possible match

```
abc(foo)def(bar)ghi
    ^^^     ^^^
```

make `*` reluctant by adding `?` after it

```
String regex = "new SingleSizeProduct((.*?))";
```

Also you need to escape `(` and `)` because as you know they represent start-end of capturing groups.

```
String regex = "new SingleSizeProduct\\((.*?)\\)";
```

BTW. Another solution would be using instead of `.*?` `[^)]*` which means, everything except `)`

```
String regex = "new SingleSizeProduct(([^)]*))";
```

Comment: taxn, it solved my issue,String regex = "new SingleSizeProduct\\((.*?)\\)";

Answer (score 2):

Escape the literal backslashes, and use a *reluctant* [quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html):

```
String regex = "new SingleSizeProduct\\((.*?)\\)";
```

([demo](http://rubular.com/r/QoDe7I3PF3))

Comment: tanx for quick response too

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` here, assuming your input stays the same.

```
String text    = "new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265858, 5430, '3XL', 75, 0, '14.90',     '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265859, 5341, 'L', 55, 0, '14.90',     '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265860, 5459, 'M', 45, 1, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265861, 5446, 'S', 35, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265862, 5458, 'XL', 60, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'),new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265863, 5511, 'XXL', 65, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL')";
String[] parts = text.split("(?<=\\)),");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Result:

```
[
 new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265858, 5430, '3XL', 75, 0, '14.90',     '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'), 
 new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265859, 5341, 'L', 55, 0, '14.90',     '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'), 
 new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265860, 5459, 'M', 45, 1, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'), 
 new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265861, 5446, 'S', 35, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'), 
 new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265862, 5458, 'XL', 60, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL'), 
 new SingleSizeProduct(422056, 1265863, 5511, 'XXL', 65, 0, '14.90', '16.50', '29.90', 'TL')
]
```

Comment: +1 assuming that input contains only `new SingleSizeProduct(...)` values. In case other values are possible like `, new Foo(...)` Pattern/Matcher would be better approach.